# Reload asterisk server after saving extension details from my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asterisk

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC. I wrote add functionality in my application to add extension details into asterisk database using asterisk realtime database configuration. But after saving extension details to asterisk database, it needs reload. So how can I reload remotely located asterisk server from my application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by self. Following code is required for reload asterisk after store all of your configuration in asterisk databases:

```
        using (var cSSH = new SshClient("asterisk server ip", "username", "secret"))
        {
            cSSH.Connect();             
            SshCommand sc = cSSH.CreateCommand("/var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf");
            sc.Execute();
            sc = cSSH.CreateCommand("asterisk -rx 'core reload'");
            sc.Execute();
            cSSH.Disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: Answer is not correct. First command rebuild freepbx configuration, second command reload all modules on asterisk, which is not nice way. Also it have no full path to asterisk binary. Put ssh secret into source code of application is REALY HUGE risk.

Comment: You might be right, but this solution works for me whether you downvote my answer., doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use asterisk REALTIME architecture, it not require reload.

Reload can be done by using AMI interface, but if you need it you probably did something wrong.

Comment: Please go through with https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Realtime+Database+Configuration